# Authorize.net gem TLS 1.2 compatibility

Tags: ruby, authorize.net

I am using authorizent gem `1.8.2`

I would like to know if it is TLS 1.2 compatible.

Comment: That's something you configure on your server

Comment: "It" is the web server, e.g. `nginx`. In order to see whether "it" is compatible, I'd need to see your web server config. For example, see: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For authorize.net's TLS upgrade, it is based on your server's OpenSSL library version.  To see if you are compatible, run the following command:

```
openssl s_client -connect secure.authorize.net:443
```

If you get a one-line error message like this:

```
6641:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s23_clnt.c:586:
```

Then you are NOT compatible.  To fix, you need to either update your OpenSSL in Linux or get the latest OpenSSL from here - https://www.openssl.org/source/

For building, you may have to configure it something like this:

```
export CFLAGS=-fPIC
./config shared
make
make install     # this one as root
```

In theory, after updating, it would be best to rebuild ruby from source.  However, absent that, there is a trick you can do:

Create a new file, I called mine ruby_openssl in the same directory as ruby.  The file should have the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
export LD_PRELOAD=/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.0:/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
exec /opt/ruby-1.8.7-p352/bin/ruby $*
```

The LD_PRELOAD should go to the shared files that were installed by installing OpenSSL, wherever you happened to install them.

Then, in your apache config, reference your new ruby_newopenssl wherever you were referencing ruby.